# Error while trying to use a CSS selector with requests-HTML

Tags: python, python-requests-html

I have a code:

```
from requests_html import HTMLSession

url = 'https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/COMP'
s = HTMLSession()

r = s.get(url)

#Both of these give the same error:

name = r.html.find('h1.D(ib) Fz(18px)', first = True).text
name = r.html.find('h1.D(ib).Fz(18px)', first = True).text

print(name)
```

which results in the following error:

```
cssselect.parser.SelectorSyntaxError: Expected selector, got <DELIM '(' at 4>
```

Sometimes putting a dot in the full class name where there is a space works (see the second version for name). I don't think I am making a mistake following the documentation, but it seems to me that the parentheses in class names here are problematic. If I use Beautifulsoup, I can get around this problem, but I really would like to understand how to fix this issue within Requests-HTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to escape the parentheses :

```py
from requests_html import HTMLSession
url = 'https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/COMP'
s = HTMLSession()

r = s.get(url)

name = r.html.find('h1.D\(ib\)', first=True).text

print(name)
```

Output:

```sh
Compass, Inc. (COMP)
```

Comment: This worked. Any chance you could explain how you arrived at this solution? I did look through the documentation and didn't find anything pertaining to this issue. I hope I didn't miss it. On a different note, is there an option in requests-HTML to select an element by its attribute? I see an option for CSS selectors, but when it comes to attributes the only thing that I can see in the documentation is how to access elements attributes after you already selected the element.

Comment: @Abramo, as for your first question: Since `(` and `)` are [metacharacters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metacharacter) in [CSS selectors](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.php), you need to _escape_ them in order for them to be treated _literally_, namely as `\(` and `\)`.

Comment: As an aside, re Python's string-literal syntax: unless _raw_ string literals (`r'...'` or `r"..."`) are used, it's better to explicitly signal the intent to retain ``\`` characters _as part of the string value_ by using ``\\`` - both for robustness and conceptual clarity